# How do I set up Robolectric in IntelliJ?

Tags: unit-testing, installation, robolectric

I know there are instructions [here](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/intellij-quick-start.html), but they are not clear to me at all. I have an existing project that's built using ANT, so I'm not Mavenized, and I'm not starting from scratch. An awesome tutorial with screenshots would be great, as I'm sure I'm not the only one who has had problems with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you can really do is to look at Pivotal's [AndroidIntelliJStarter](https://github.com/pivotal/AndroidIntelliJStarter) project, and mimick what they are doing. This is what I had to do to get my project setup.